# How to access key contents of nested hashmap

Tags: java

I'm creating an inverted index for an information retrieval course and can't figure out how to see if a word is in my nested hashmap.

"inner" contains a word & its frequency while the "invertedIndex" contains the name of the document it occurs in.

When processing a search, I'm trying to see if the user input defined as "query" is in the inner hashmap. I'm pretty sure the error is arising from the nested for loop at the bottom of my code...

My code is below.

```
   public class PositionalIndex extends Stemmer{

  // no more than this many input files needs to be processed
  final static int MAX_NUMBER_OF_INPUT_FILES = 100;

  // an array to hold Gutenberg corpus file names
  static String[] inputFileNames = new String[MAX_NUMBER_OF_INPUT_FILES];

  static int fileCount = 0;

  // loads all files names in the directory subtree into an array
  // violates good programming practice by accessing a global variable (inputFileNames)
  public static void listFilesInPath(final File path) {
      for (final File fileEntry : path.listFiles()) {
          if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
              listFilesInPath(fileEntry);
          }
          else if (fileEntry.getName().endsWith((".txt")))  {
              inputFileNames[fileCount++] = fileEntry.getPath();
          }
      }
      System.out.println("File count: " + fileCount);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    // did the user provide correct number of command line arguments?
    // if not, print message and exit
    if (args.length != 1){
        System.err.println("Number of command line arguments must be 1");
        System.err.println("You have given " + args.length + " command line arguments");
        System.err.println("Incorrect usage. Program terminated");
        System.err.println("Correct usage: java Ngrams <path-to-input-files>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // extract input file name from command line arguments
    // this is the name of the file from the Gutenberg corpus
    String inputFileDirName = args[0];

    System.out.println("Input files directory path name is: " + inputFileDirName);

    // collects file names and write them to
    listFilesInPath(new File (inputFileDirName));

    // wordPattern specifies pattern for words using a regular expression
    Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");

    // wordMatcher finds words by spotting word word patterns with input
    Matcher wordMatcher;

    // a line read from file
    String line;

    // br for efficiently reading characters from an input stream
    BufferedReader br = null;

    // an extracted word from a line
    String word;

    // simplified version of porterStemmer
    Stemmer porterStemmer = new Stemmer();

    System.out.println("Processing files...");

    // create an instance of the Stemmer class
    Stemmer stemmer = new Stemmer();

    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> invertedIndex = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
    Map<String, Integer> inner = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // process one file at a time
    for (int index = 0; index < fileCount; index++){

        // open the input file, read one line at a time, extract words
        // in the line, extract characters in a word, write words and
        // character counts to disk files
        try {
            // get a BufferedReader object, which encapsulates
            // access to a (disk) file
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileNames[index]));

            // as long as we have more lines to process, read a line
            // the following line is doing two things: makes an assignment
            // and serves as a boolean expression for while test
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // process the line by extracting words using the wordPattern
                wordMatcher = wordPattern.matcher(line);

                // process one word at a time
                while ( wordMatcher.find() ) {
                    // extract the word
                    word = line.substring(wordMatcher.start(), wordMatcher.end());
                    word = word.toLowerCase();

                    //use Stemmer class to stem word & convert to lowercase
                    porterStemmer.stemWord(word);
                    if (!inner.containsKey(word)) {
                        inner.put(word, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      inner.put(word, inner.get(word) + 1);
                    }
              } // end one word at a time while
            } // end outer while
            invertedIndex.put(inputFileNames[index], inner);
            /*for(String x : inner.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(x);
              }*/
            inner.clear();
          } // end try
              catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("File " + inputFileNames[index] + " not found. Program terminated.\n");
                System.exit(1);
                }
              } // end for
        System.out.print("Enter a query: ");
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String query = kbd.next();

        for(String fileName : invertedIndex.keySet()) {
            for(String wordInFile : invertedIndex.get(fileName).keySet())
            {
              if(wordInFile.equals(query))
              {
                System.out.println(query + " was found in document " + fileName);
              }
            }
          }


  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of clear inner , why not new inner in for loop? You can also refine you add count code to  inner.put(word,  inner.getOrDefault(word,0)+1);

Comment: Can you show us your wordPattern ?

Comment: I'm going through 14,000 documents so wouldn't creating a new inner for each document be counter-productive? My reasoning was store all the words & their frequencies in "inner", add them to "invertedIndex", and then clear the contents of inner to be ready for the next document. But maybe I'm misunderstanding your suggestion of "creating a new inner in the for loop"...

Comment: Because you clear your "inner" map each time. You may try to print the size of inner from invertedIndex to make sure it is not empty .

Comment: I updated my code so you can see the entire class as well as a few global variables, but my wordPattern is just   Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you invoking:

`inner.clear()`

it seems that a new inner map needs to be created every time and then added to invertedIndex; instead of clearing it as data are lost.

Comment: Wow... Can't believe my mistake was that. In my head, by adding inner to invertedIndex I was saving its contents but now I see that I was not. Thanks so much!

Comment: ;) Please consider accepting it as answer or voting it up as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(String w : invertedIndex.keySet()) {
   Map<String, Integer> fileWordMap =  invertedIndex.get(w)
   if(fileWordMap.containsKey(query))
   {
       System.out.println(query + " was found in document " + w);
   }
}
```

or as per your original code

```
for(String fileName : invertedIndex.keySet()) {
   for(String wordInFile : invertedIndex.get(fileName).keySet())
   {
       if(wordInFile.equals(query))
       {
          System.out.println(query + " was found in document " + fileName);
       }
    }
}
```

As a tip, try having variable names that can tell you what the code is doing :) Its very easy to get confused if we only use random variable names

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm still not getting the print statement to display so it's never getting inside the if even though my query is certainly contained in the document... Perhaps it's an error with my storing of the words/frequencies in "innner"? Let me know if anything sticks out to you!

Comment: Do you try equalsIgnoreCase ?

Comment: I made all the words lower case before storing them in the inner hashmap, but I really appreciate your response!